# Create rolling minimum of groupby in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, min

I have an R - dataframe with the following format:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1618 | 01/01/23 | 10 |
| 1618 | 02/01/23 | 10 |
| 1618 | 03/01/23 | 6 |
| 1618 | 04/01/23 | 8 |
| 1618 | 05/01/23 | 10 |
| 1618 | 06/01/23 | 4 |
| 3512 | 01/01/23 | 1 |
| 3512 | 02/01/23 | 1 |
| 3512 | 03/01/23 | 3 |
| 3512 | 04/01/23 | 4 |
| 3512 | 05/01/23 | 0 |
| 3512 | 06/01/23 | 8 |

I want to do a groupby on the id and add a column with the lowest value so far and a column showing the delta in lowest value. For the example above the expected output looks like:

| id | date | value | lowest | delta lowest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1618 | 01/01/23 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 1618 | 02/01/23 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 1618 | 03/01/23 | 6 | 6 | -4 |
| 1618 | 04/01/23 | 8 | 6 | 0 |
| 1618 | 05/01/23 | 10 | 6 | 0 |
| 1618 | 06/01/23 | 4 | 4 | -2 |
| 3512 | 01/01/23 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3512 | 02/01/23 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3512 | 03/01/23 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 3512 | 04/01/23 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 3512 | 05/01/23 | 0 | 0 | -1 |
| 3512 | 06/01/23 | 8 | 0 | 0 |

How can I best approach this in R?

Comment: base r: ```within(within(df, lowest <- ave(value, id, FUN = cummin)), delta_lowes <- ave(lowest, id, FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x))))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using `cummin` and `diff`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(lowest = cummin(value), delta_lowest = c(0, diff(lowest)), .by = id)
     id     date value lowest delta_lowest
1  1618 01/01/23    10     10            0
2  1618 02/01/23    10     10            0
3  1618 03/01/23     6      6           -4
4  1618 04/01/23     8      6            0
5  1618 05/01/23    10      6            0
6  1618 06/01/23     4      4           -2
7  3512 01/01/23     1      1            0
8  3512 02/01/23     1      1            0
9  3512 03/01/23     3      1            0
10 3512 04/01/23     4      1            0
11 3512 05/01/23     0      0           -1
12 3512 06/01/23     8      0            0
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1618L, 1618L, 1618L, 1618L, 1618L, 1618L, 
3512L, 3512L, 3512L, 3512L, 3512L, 3512L), date = c("01/01/23", 
"02/01/23", "03/01/23", "04/01/23", "05/01/23", "06/01/23", "01/01/23", 
"02/01/23", "03/01/23", "04/01/23", "05/01/23", "06/01/23"), 
    value = c(10L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
    8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```